# xslで表の各行にあるセル（entry）数をカウントし、その値を各行比較して一番多い値を結果に出す

Tags: xsl, xslt

お手数ですが、お知恵いただきたく投稿させていただきました。
元となるxml構造の表で列数定義やセルの連結情報がないため、正しい列数が算出できず困っています。

**やったこと**
1.　XSL1.0で各行のセル数は拾い、羅列したものの、その値をから行の最大値を比較できず断念。
2.　XSL2.0でテンポラリーツリーで配列を使い値を比較。...が、経験値が浅く、かつ参考が少ないため解決策模索。（←現在）

環境：saxonb9-1-0-8j、JavaSEランタイム1.8.0、Windows10（1903）

**やりたいこと**
xslで表の各行（row）にあるセル（entry）数をカウントし、カウントした各行の値を比較し一番多いセルの数（最大値）を結果に出す。
※行数・列数は固定されない前提です。
※元となるxmlにセル数を追記しました。（ここで求めたい結果はセル数4）

**元となるxml**

```
<table tocentry = "1">
    <table.group charoff = "50" align = "left">
        <table.body valign = "top">
            セル数2：<row><entry valign = "middle" align = "center">000-00</entry><entry valign = "middle" align = "center">西海岸</entry></row>
            セル数4：<row><entry valign = "top">999-01</entry><entry valign = "top">海</entry><entry valign = "top">-</entry><entry valign = "top">-</entry></row>
            セル数4：<row><entry valign = "top">999-02</entry><entry valign = "top">海</entry><entry valign = "top">-</entry><entry valign = "top">-</entry></row>
            セル数3：<row><entry valign = "top">123-45</entry><entry valign = "top">北海</entry><entry valign = "top">-</entry></row>
            セル数2：<row><entry valign = "middle" align = "center">678-90</entry><entry valign = "middle" align = "center">南海</entry></row>
        </table.body>
    </table.group>
</table>
```

**XSLT内容（XSL2.0）**
調整途中のため、間違っているところや汚いところもあるとおもいますがソースを記載させていただきます。

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                xmlns:xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                                xmlns:rdf = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                                xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="table/table.group">
    <xsl:variable name="cols-count" as="element()*">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//row">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" as="xs:integer"/>
            <xsl:element name="array{$i}"><xsl:value-of select="count(.//entry)"/></xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <table>
        <xsl:attribute name="tabletype">all</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="format">all</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="cols"><xsl:value-of select="$cols-count[0]"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="width">100%</xsl:attribute>
        <!--<xsl:call-template name="cols-count" />-->
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table.head">
    <thead>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </thead>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table.body">
    <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tbody>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry">
    <td>
        <xsl:if test="@hspan"><xsl:attribute name="hspan"><xsl:value-of select="@hspan" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@vspan"><xsl:attribute name="vspan"><xsl:value-of select="@vspan" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="@rotate"><xsl:attribute name="rotate"><xsl:value-of select="@rotate" /></xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
        <p><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: <xsl:variable name="cols-count" as="element()*">の中身を、検証した内容に差し替えました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お問い合わせでやりたいことはCALSテーブルでいうところの、`tgroup/@cols`を求めたいことだと思います．

コード中の

```
<xsl:attribute name="cols"><xsl:value-of select="$cols-count[0]"/></xsl:attribute>
```

の代わりに

```
<xsl:attribute name="cols" select="max(for $row in table.body/row return(count($row/entry)))"/>
```

ではいかがでしょうか？

手元のOxygen Developerで変換してみた結果は、以下のように`cols="4"`で出力されます．

```
<table xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" tabletype="all" format="all" cols="4" width="100%">
```

一度お試しください．

蛇足ですが、`saxonb9-1-0-8j`はXSLT 2.0の初期実装です．最新のSaxonだとXSLT 3.0も使えて大変お得です．

以上

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
こちらでも検証まして、cols="4"とカウントされました。
また、列数のパターンを変えて検証しても求めていたことができたので問題ありません。

Comment: saxonのバージョンの件、ありがとうございます。
XSLT3.0に関する情報はXST2.0よりもさらに少ないですが、XSLT2.0も使えるならとりあえずSaxonを最新にしようと思います。